# Xcode 6 LaunchScreen.xib wrong window size for iOS7 iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xib

I've created my project in Xcode 6 and I'm using default LaunchScreen.xib file. In iOS 8 everything is working fine, however when I'm testing on iOS 7.0.3 project seems not working with iPhone 5 - I've got black bars on top and bottom. As I've said, on iPhone 5 iOS 8 everything is working fine.

When I take a look into the xib file:

```
Size - freeform (changing to inferred doesn't help)
Orientation - inferred
Status bar - none
Top bar - inferred
Bottom bar - inferred
```

Any idea how to fix it?

--edit--

I've created a new project via pattern (Single View Application -> Devices (universal)), changed only project info -> iOS deployment target to 5.0. When I run on iPhone 5s iOS 7.0.3 simulator the screen doesn't get filled with application. This seems to be bug made by Apple.

Comment: Is this in the simulator or on a real device?

Comment: @Liron Simulator, I don't have Retina 4 device with iOS7. I'm filling bug report @ Apple.

Comment: What do you have in the launchscreen xib?

Comment: @Liron This, what is added by default. I didn't make any changes. Just created new project and changed deployment target.

Comment: Actually - 1 sec. iOS7 doesn't support launchscreen.xib's, does it? That would only work on an iOS8 launch. For iOS7 it would be using the launch images.

Comment: @Liron Isn't it backward compatible? I thought there will be something like a screenshot from the xib in pre iOS8 devices. But you're probably right. Good I haven't managed to fill that bug yet. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: just choose your project, open tab General and click to "Use Asset" in Launch Image Source field. Xcode auto gen defaults image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On iOS7 or earlier, you have to use launch images. From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

> In iOS 8 and later, you can create a XIB or storyboard file instead of
>   a static launch image. When you create a launch file in Interface
>   Builder, you use size classes to define different layouts for
>   different display environments and you use Auto Layout to make minor
>   adjustments. Using size classes and Auto Layout means that you can
>   create a single launch file that looks good on all devices and display
>   environments. (For an overview of display environments and size
>   classes, see Build In Adaptivity; to learn how to use size classes in
>   Interface Builder, see Size Classes Design Help.)
>
> If you also need to support earlier versions of iOS, you can continue
>   to supply static launch images in addition to a launch file.

Comment: Also, if you're using size classes, you have to turn them off for iOS 7.